# display DataFrame() values in bold font in one row only

Tags: pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

having dataframe **summary** being called directly from jupyter cell

```
summary #(Shift + Enter)
```

how can I make the highlighted row only (last row) in bold font?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please, please provide the code to at least generate the dataframe you are posting.

For what you want, you can use style.applymap() function. The rest is to find the correct properties of font that can be set to bold and how to set index of last row.

```
import pandas as pd

def df_style(val):
    return "font-weight: bold"

summary = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1620, 203, 392, 651, 2236]],
                       index=["None", "Total"])

# get a handle on the row that starts with `"Total"`, i.e., the last row here
last_row = pd.IndexSlice[summary.index[summary.index == "Total"], :]
# and apply styling to it via the `subset` arg; first arg is styler function above
summaryStyled = summary.style.applymap(df_style, subset=last_row)

display(summaryStyled)
```

And below is the output:

[image]

Comment: @B.Malysz I mean to post the code to generate the dataframe you posted in the picture. instead of letting others back-engineering. I assume that's nothing confidential.

Comment: This code is not working for my case. I also want to ask, where do you use ```df_style``` function?

Comment: @DionisiusPratama Indeed it was mistaken, now fixed; function is used as the first argument to `style.applymap`.

Comment: Styler.applymap has been deprecated. Use Styler.map instead.

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
def highlight_max(x):
    return ['font-weight: bold' if v == x.loc[4] else ''
                for v in x]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2))
df.style.apply(highlight_max)
```

[image]

Comment: I got this error: ```ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().``` Do you have any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: loc[4] is wrong sintax. Use `iloc[4]` inside.

Answer (score 2):

A better option for the 'last row' would be.

```
def highlight_last(x):
    '''
    highlight the last row in a Series BOLD.
    '''
    return ['font-weight: bold' if v == x.iloc[-1] else '' for v in x]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).