# pandas conditionally format field in bold

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,2, 3, 4],
                   'bar':[[1,2,0.04], [1,2,0.04], [1,2,0.06], np.nan]})
display(df)

def stars(x, sign_level):
    if x is np.nan:
        return ''
    else:
        p_value = x[2]
        if p_value < sign_level:
            return '*'
        else:
            return ''

df['marker'] = df.bar.apply(stars, sign_level=0.05)
df
```

Instead of adding a column with a star in case the result is considered significant, is it possible to format the cell (like in an Excel sheet) as bold?

[display DataFrame() values in bold font in one row only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51938245/display-dataframe-values-in-bold-font-in-one-row-only/51962472) seems to be able to format a whole row - I would like to reformat only a specific cell

[Conditionally format Python pandas cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203959/conditionally-format-python-pandas-cell)

seems similar, though they only change the background, not format as bold.

### edit

the code below can already change the background color - I just do not know how to format as bold.

```
def highlight_significant(x, sign_level):
    if x is np.nan:
        return ''
    else:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            p_value = x[2]
            color = 'lightgreen' if p_value < sign_level else ''
            if p_value < sign_level:
                return 'background-color: %s' % color
            else:
                return ''
        else:
            return ''

df.style.applymap(highlight_significant, sign_level=0.05)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might help ...

Set up a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],
               axis=1)
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan
```

create functional you can apply to add bold based on a condition of you define

```
def negative_bold(val):


    bold = 'bold' if val < 0 else ''


    return 'font-weight: %s' % bold
```

Apply the function to the style of the data frame

```
s = df.style.applymap(negative_bold)
```

Look at the dataframe, you should find all negative numbers are bold

[image]

I looked here https://mode.com/example-gallery/python_dataframe_styling/ and here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

**EDIT** Adding to this answer ...

Combining two styles

I have two functions, one to highlight yellow the number is negative and another make the number bold if negative

Negative_yellow

```
def negative_yellow(val):


    color = 'yellow' if val < 0 else ''


    return 'background-color:' + color
```

Negative bold

```
def negative_bold(val):


    bold = 'bold' if val < 0 else ''


    return 'font-weight: %s' % bold
```

I apply the two the data frame like this

```
df.style.\
    applymap(negative_yellow).\
    applymap(negative_bold)
```

[image]

I imagine there are more elegant ways of doing this. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Cool. Can multiple styles (color + font-weight) also be combined?

Comment: And indeed, this is possible by simply combining `foo;bar` the individual styles with a semicolon.

Comment: I updated my answer to combine two functions to make bold and yellow where a number is negative @GeorgHeiler . There are likely more elegant ways of doing this :)